# Anyone know how to solve the error of "collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status" when a program in C is running?

Tags: c, ide, sublimetext3

First of all I'm at the first year of computer science so I'm a beginner in programming yet, then forgive me for my lack of knowledge. Well, my problem basically is an error that is shown in the screen everytime when I try to run(by the way I'm using Sublime Text) a program in C. In this case was a simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {    
    //print the heading of the game
    printf("*****************************************\n");
    printf("* Wellcome to the our guessing game *\n");
    printf("*****************************************\n");
    int secretnumber =  42;
    int guess;

    printf("What is your guess?");
    scanf("%d", &guess);
    printf("Your guess was %d \n", guess);
}
```

OUTPUT:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file Olamundo.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.3s]

You know, i tried some solutions like move the folder where the executable lies and place it in the root(in my case Mateus(C:)), give all the permissions to the folder, turn off the antivirus(in my case i just using the Windows defender), finish the task using the the Task manager but nothing worked. Please, help me i really don't know what else i can do.

Comment: Your problem is in building (compiling and linking) the program.  Not with running it - since the process of compiling and linking must succeed in creating an executable, before you can run the executable.  collect2 is one of the programs run during the link stage.   In any event, describe the command (or commands. if you are using more than one) that you are using to build your program.   That will be where the problem is.

Comment: 1. Try to create a new file in the folder you plan to use for the executable. -- 2. Try to build your program outside of SublimeText. -- 3. Check the options of Sublime Text where it thinks it should build the executable.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, your problem is that you're trying to run a program that is interactive from within Sublime; it doesn't support that. Sublime captures output your program sends to `stdout` and `stderr` and displays it in the output panel, but it does't connect the panel to `stdin`.

So, the scenario you're encountering works like this:

1. You run your program, which is interactive (in your case it prompts for input via `scanf()`, and it launches and prompts you for input
2. You try to enter input, but nothing happens because `stdin` isn't connected.
3. You try to run your program again (or modify it and build it again thinking you might have an issue).
4. The version you previously tried to run is still running in the background waiting for input you can't provide, and windows locks executable files while the program is running. So, when the linker (`collect2`) tries to link the executable during the build, it can't because the file is locked, hence the permission error.

You can clear the error by killing the program running in the background, which you can do via the `Tools > Cancel Build` ***if you do it before this error occurs***; if you've already seen the error this likely won't work because this only cancels the most recent build, which would be the one where the error occurred.

The other thing you can do is use something external to kill it; the task manager on windows, `kill` from a terminal on Linux/OSX, etc. You'll need to do it this way if you're already seeing the error.

Note however that this doesn't solve your underlying problem because you're still trying to run an interactive program. In order to do that from within Sublime you need to create a custom `sublime-build` that allows for this. Generally you'd either have it spawn an external terminal and run the program in there, or use a package like [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) if you want to keep it internal.

In order to set this up, you need to be familiar with the sequence of commands that are needed to compile, link and run a program in one command, which you can get by checking what the build system you're currently using is (assuming you didn't create it yourself).

This video on [buffering and interactive builds in Sublime](https://youtu.be/P5FXeB4k1bw) (disclaimer, I'm the author) has information and examples of how Terminus can be used for something like this if you'd like more information.